# CakePHP model saving to wrong table

Tags: php, cakephp

In my User model I have the following relationship:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User'=>array(
            'className'              => 'User',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends',
            'with'                   => 'Friend',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'friend_id'
        )
);
```

Which links users to users as friends. However when I do something with a single user like change the password or edit the user details (unrelated to the friends), it will start doing stuff in the friends table such as delete all existing records and then add in empty rows of data...

Have I set the relationship up wrong? Should the naming be different, so that when I'm dealing with the `$this->User` it is not touching friends?

**Edit: Since posting this question I have changed the user_id and friend_id to user1_id and user2_id to prevent Cake doing any automagic with the fields by assuming that they are primary keys or anything as explained below by nIcO. But the same problem still happens!**

Comment: What's the actual query look like?  You can use `$log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false); debug($log)` to get the output

Comment: http://pastebin.com/Xx0Rc6gg

Comment: Did you try doing  `$this->recursive = 0` in your model before the actual Save call? If you are calling save from the controller, it will be `$this->User->recursive=0` before calling the save method. I will try to setup a test scenario tomorrow on my system if that does not work. --Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few ways to implement a friendship association, because there are two directions in a friendship. You can say that user A is friends with user B, but also user B is friend with user A.

When a person creates a friendship in the database. You'll have to create two records in the join table to represent this friendship in both directions (assuming you want a dual direction).

That covers the concepts of direction.

You may be experiencing problems with records disappearing, because CakePHP by default will erase all join data rows for a record when it's updated. Take a look at the description for the 'unique' option on a HABTM.

> **unique**: If true (default value) cake will first delete existing relationship records in the foreign keys table before inserting new ones, when updating a record. So existing associations need to be passed again when updating.

That means that you always have to include the HABTM data when updating the record. Otherwise those records will be erased, and updated with what was passed.

Now the most basic friendship setup you can create would involve two tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
   `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `users_users` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `friend_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user` (`user_id`),
  KEY `friend` (`friend_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The first table 'users' will hold our user data, and the second 'users_users' is the HABTM join table. Note the name, that it's users_users because it's joining itself.

You will still need to create two models in CakePHP.

The first is the User.php which will describe a user in the system. We'll be using mostly the defaults in CakePHP to get this to work. So the HABTM is just one line 'Friend'.

```
class User extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'User';
    var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
          'Friend'
    );
}
```

Now, CakePHP will complain that the table users_friends is missing. We need to create a Friend model, but point it at the users table instead.

```
class Friend extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Friend';
    var $useTable = 'users';
}
```

Now CakePHP will use users_users table as the join. The Friend model now describes a user who is a friend.

It's important to understand that you will have to create the friends in both directions. When you save data for user A says he/she is friends with user B, then you will also have to save user B and say he/she is friends with user A. Otherwise, only one user will have the friendship defined.

There is another answer here that defines the dual direction of the friendship using aliases, but I recommend not implementing that as it adds extra SQL query work for CakePHP that might not be needed by your application. When you read records for User A, then you only need to know who their friends are, but no the other way around.

You could create a Behavior that ensures the friendship go both ways when user records are updated. That would be more efficient.

> **NOTE:** My code example is for CakePHP **1.3** which is what I'm currently using, but it should work in 2.x just fine.

Comment: The friendship model works fine in my app already. That's not my question. Rather the issue is that Cake is using the Friend model when I use the users table because it is linked to itself.

Comment: In your question you define the HABTM to re-use the same 'User' model by defining 'classname' as 'User'. I don't think that is wise. Where as, I created a new Friend.php model for Cake to use and pointed it to the same table. I don't think that will cause any problems.

Comment: It breaks my Friend stuff though as now I get the following error: `SELECT `Friend`.`id`, `Friend`.`friend_id` FROM `db52704_favorr`.`users` AS `Friend` WHERE `Friend`.`user_id` = '6' AND `Friend`.`status` = 1`

Comment: So it's looking in the users table for the friend_id because I have told the Friend model to look at the users table.

Comment: @Cameron I'm a little confused. sorry. friend_id should only be in the users_users table (the join table).

Comment: It is only in the users_users table. They are structured EXACTLY as you have shown. But because you are linking the Friend model to the users table it is looking in there for the friend stuff instead of looking at the correct table.

Comment: When you say "correct type" which table are you referring to as being the correct one? There should only be two tables.

Comment: There is only two tables: users and users_users. But the Friend model has declared users as its table `useTable = 'users'` so therefore looking for data via the Friend model means it looks in the wrong table. Either way I was having no issues with the Friend model setup. The problem is that when I save data for just a User it touches friend relationships because Cake is trying to be smart and messing up.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21785/discussion-between-mathew-foscarini-and-cameron)

Answer (score 2):

I would strongly suggest doing this with a real Friends model. Set it up like this:

```
User hasMany FriendList
User hasMany FriendOf (alias of FriendList)

FriendList belongsTo User
FriendList belongsTo Friend (alias of User)
```

Example code:

```
Table definitions (skeleton):

users:
  id
  name

friend_lists:
  id
  user_id
  friend_id

Model Definitions:

class User extends AppModel {
  var $hasMany = array(
    'FriendList',
    'FriendOf' => array(
      'className' => 'FriendList',
      'foreignKey' => 'friend_id'
    )
  );
}

class FriendList extends AppModel {
  var $belongsTo = array(
    'User',
    'Friend' => array(
      'className' => 'User',
      'foreignKey' => 'friend_id'
     )
  );
}
```

Comment: Could you show an example of how this would be set up in models?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... do you want the relationship definitions? The models are what I just listed.

Comment: What models should I create and what should be in them based on your structure above.

Comment: I think this is what you're asking for: https://gist.github.com/962c090fa59ec9d225a3

Comment: Version in the answer above should be used, not the gist (which I stupidly created without logging in, so I can't edit it).

Comment: I have had a go implementing that into my app but it's just blowing the app up and causing random variables and other stuff to not work, could you give a few more details regarding it. Such as what models will Cake be auto-creating... Friend perhaps? And will I still be able to do things like this: pastebin.com/08Zhd1FM or will I have to do things differently based on the above changes. Thanks

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21519/discussion-between-utoxin-and-cameron)

Comment: @MathewFoscarini I can't get it working as I get the following errors: `The error in the log is: 2012-12-21 07:57:53 Error: [MissingTableException] Table friend_lists for model FriendOf was not found in datasource default.`
And if i rename my table to friend_lists then I get a new error log: `Table friend_lists_users for model FriendListsUser was not found in datasource default.`
So it would seem it's auto creating lots of models based on those 'new' relationships

Answer (score 0):

Your join table is called `friends` and uses a model called `Friend`. And by looking at the HABTM relation declaration, it seems that the `friends` table contains a field called `user_id` and a field called `friend_id`.

Having a `friend_id` field in a `friends` table is like having a `user_id` field in a `users` table, which you would probably not do. And I guess that Cake doesn't like it because `friend_id` is seen by Cake as a foreign key pointing to *another* model called `Friend`.

Anyway, dealing with HABTM between the same table is not easy with HABTM relations (see [HABTM with self requires 2x the rows in join table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232011/habtm-with-self-requires-2x-the-rows-in-join-table)) and you should probably use a join model instead (see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through-the-join-model)

Comment: I tried changing the fields to user1_id and user2_id but the same problem still happens and it borks all data in the friends table when I edit a users details. So that can't be the issue...

Comment: If possible could you show an example of how I could fix this relationship using a join model as I don't understand this problem at all and seems like Cake is doing some automagic that I can't see.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create a Model that has the same alias/name as one used in the hasAndBelongsToMany relationship. This has caused me nothing but headaches with CakePHP.

For example;

I have a model called "Company" that HABTM "User" records. So there is a table called "companyies_users" in my database.

You might be tempted to do something like this in your Company model.

```
var $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
    'User'=>array('with'=>'CompanyUser')
);
```

And then create a "CompanyUser" model, because you want to store extra data in the association.

Don't do this. I don't know why, but Cake is unpredictable of when it will auto-create a model named "CompanyUser" and when it will actually load the the PHP file you created.

It's best in your model that defines the HABTM to use the default association, and then create a Model of a **different** name from the table, and use that to process the records. This ensures that CakePHP will also uses an auto-generated model and work correctly.

So in my example, I create a model called "Members" that sets the "useTable" varaible to "companies_users".

Now I know when I use the "Company" model CakePHP will handle the HABTM correctly, and if I need to access those connection records, then I use the "Members" model.

The risk of using the "with" option is that you never know when CakePHP will fail, and auto-generate the mode. In which case, none of your callbacks or behaviors will happen.

EDIT:

To more directly answer the question.

Modify the User.php Model file so that the HABTM uses more of the defaults.

```
 public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array('Friend');
```

Ensure, you do not have a UserFriend.php Model file defined for the join table. If you need to modify the join table, use a model with a different alias pointing to that table in the database.

Comment: Could you give an example of how I would fix my problem when doing HABTM on the same table through another table then? Thanks

Comment: Tried that but I get the error `[MissingTableException] Table friends_users for model FriendsUser was not found in datasource default`. Changing the table name then causes the error that table friends is missing... so it's expecting both tables? Also when you say *"use a model with a different alias pointing to that table in the database."* what do you mean exactly?

Comment: In a HABTM there are three models. User is the first, Friend is the second, UserFriend is the join. The last one should be auto-created by Cake. So if you want to read/write to that table. Create a model called "Other" and set useTable to point to "users_friends" in the database.

Comment: But I don't have a Friend 'physical' model. Could you perhaps show what exactly I should have e.g. what model files and what should be in each to create the relationship you think I should have.

Comment: @Cameron what version of CakePHP are you using?

Comment: I have to apologize. I completely missed the fact that you were trying to join a table with itself. No wonder you were confused by my answer.

Comment: No problem :) Do you know how I can fix this then when doing a join on the same table? It works fine except for Cake touching the Friend stuff whenever the User model is used e.g. saving profile, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is caused by declaring the association incorrectly. Try this:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Friend'=>array(
            'className'              => 'Friend',
            'joinTable'              => 'friends',
            'foreignKey'             => 'user_id',
            'associationForeignKey'  => 'friend_id'
        )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to Cakephp HABTM Documentation,

> HABTM data is treated like a complete set, each time a new data
>   association is added the complete set of associated rows in database
>   is dropped and created again so you will always need to pass the whole
>   data set for saving.

From 2.1, with

> You can set unique setting to keepExisting circumvent losing extra data during the save operation. 
>   I.e,

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'User' => array(
                ....
                'unique' => 'keepExisting',
                ....
        ),
);
```

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html#hasmany-through